# AttributeError: 'Paragraph' object has no attribute 'add_hyperlink'

Tags: python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I am getting below error while creating Table of contents using python .

```
  File "h:\Heath Check\Word document.py", line 74, in <module>
hyperlink = toc.add_hyperlink(heading.text, heading)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

AttributeError: 'Paragraph' object has no attribute 'add_hyperlink' ..

Below is my code: `

```
import docx
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from docx.table import Table
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import qn

    # Open the Word document
    doc = docx.Document(f'{docfilename}.docx')
    
    
    # Get all the headings in the document
    headings = []
    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'):
            headings.append(paragraph)
    
    # Create the table of contents
    toc = doc.add_paragraph()
    toc.add_run('Table of Contents').bold = True
    toc.alignment = docx.enum.text.WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
    toc_format = toc.paragraph_format
    toc_format.space_before = docx.shared.Pt(12)
    toc_format.space_after = docx.shared.Pt(12)
    
    for heading in headings:
        # Add a hyperlink to the heading
        hyperlink = toc.add_hyperlink(heading.text, heading)
        # Add a dot leader to align the page numbers
        toc.add_run('\t').add_tab_stop(docx.shared.Cm(14), docx.enum.text.WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT, docx.shared.Pt(6))
        # Add the page number
        toc.add_run(str(doc.index(heading)+1)).add_tab_stop(docx.shared.Cm(15), docx.enum.text.WD_TAB_ALIGNMENT.RIGHT, docx.shared.Pt(6))
        # Add a line break
        toc.add_run().add_break(docx.enum.text.WD_BREAK.LINE)
    
    # Save the document
    
    
    doc.save(f'{docfilename}.docx')
```

I have tried googling a lot and cant find a solution . All i want is python script to generate Table of contents at first page  from a word document ( documents has heading and text ) ..

Any help would be appreciated.